# Find The Area Of $\gamma(t)=(at-a\sin t,a-a\cos t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of $\gamma(t)=(at-a\sin t,a-a\cos t)$ where $t\in[0,2\pi], a>0$

I have bought to use Green's theorem $A=\frac{1}{2}\oint_\gamma(-ydx+xdy)$

$\gamma(t)=(at-a\sin t,a-a\cos t)$

$\gamma'(t)=(a-a\cos t,a\sin t)$

$A=\frac{1}{2}\oint_\gamma(-ydx+xdy)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(-(a-a\cos t)^2+a^2t\sin t-a^2\sin^2 t )dt=\\=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(-2a^2+2a^2\cos t+a^2\sin t)dt=\frac{1}{2}(-2a^2t+2a^2\sin t-a^2\cos t)|_{0}^{2\pi}=-4a^2\pi$

Which can not be as it is negative, where did it went wrong? I did not use the fact that $a>0$ maybe I had to try other integral

Comment: Your $\gamma$ is not closed, don't you need that?

Comment: Your $\gamma$ should be closed and positively oriented.

Comment: I don't think you can find the area of a curve. I think you mean the area enclosed by the curve. Before using Green's Theorem you have to check to see if it is a simple closed curve. Also, maybe your algebra is just sloppy--where did the t sin t term go? Are you just missing a t? Maybe a > 0 has something to do with the way the curve is drawn, like its orientation. You need a positive orientation to apply Green's Theorem.

Comment: Over $[0,2\pi]$ the curve traces out one cycle of a cycloid.  This is not a closed curve.  If we close it with a line from $(2\pi a,0)$ to $(0,0)$, then the curve goes around the region in a clockwise direction, and our equations are oreinted for a counter-clockwise path.  The reversed orientation flips the sign.

Comment: @DougM so I can integrate from $2\pi$ to $0$ or to flip the sign, as for closing the curve, I need to remove the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ there $y=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red line is your curve.

[image]

If you don't close the curve, you don't have an enclosed area.  The line y=0 will suffice to close the curve.

As for your integration:  You can think $\frac 12 (x\ dy - y\ dx)$ as the green area.  And the integral will be the sum of triangles with small changes in $(x,y)$  Since we are traversing clockwise, that area is $\frac 12 (x\ dy - y\ dx)$ which is of course the negative of the more familiar $\frac 12 (y\ dx - x\ dy)$ associated with counter-clockwise paths.

As far what does the line y=0 do to your integration? As all triangles connecting the origin to this path are degenerate triangles of 0 area, it has 0 impact.